# Laravel authentication for register

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

laravel authentication model

Is there any possible to make /register only you logged

How to make it with : (Auth::check()) ??

Comment: Give us some more details of what you want to achieve.

Comment: do you want management panel?say more!

Comment: If you don't give details and/or show effort in questions, your questions is more likely to be considered as incomplete by reviewers and then closed.

Comment: Try to explain more deeply what you need to do.

Comment: I think what he  is asking here is, if its possible to allow only unauthenticated users to have access to the URL /register ...which I think is the work of a middleware

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default in construct of **\app\Http\Controllers\Auth\AuthController.php** we have **middleware guest** for all except logout:

```
public function __construct()
{
    $this->middleware('guest', ['except' => [
            'logout',
        ]
    ]);
}
```

**Middleware guest** link for:

```
'guest' => \App\Http\Middleware\RedirectIfAuthenticated::class,
```

And use **handle** method:

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    if ($this->auth->check())
    {
        return new RedirectResponse(url('/'));
    }

    return $next($request);
}
```

It's mean that everybody who try access all Auth method except logout **will be redirected to main page**.

Answer (score 0):

You should look at middleware if your are at laravel 5: https://laravel.com/docs/master/middleware

And filters for laravel 4: https://laravel.com/docs/4.2/routing